# Is there a way to uses strings as variable names for entry boxes in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I'm trying to make an app in python/tkinter that allows you to create a roster for a hockey team. I want to generate the "new_roster" frame based on the parameter number of players on the team, and have thus managed to create a variable amount of entry boxes for each player, but am not able to extract the values from said entry boxes.

In my current code, a list is generated based on the number of players the user wants on their team by adding a "z" to an empty string. The next function then iterates through the list, sets the string = Entry(frame, xxx), I initially tried with an int, but it doesn't seem to matter. I also tried making the str a StringVar but it didn't work either.

Every time I try to reference the entry boxes after their creation like

```
a = (player_list[0])
b = a.get
```

I get the following error:

error: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'

it's kinda long so: https://repl.it/@masoneischens/StableToughTheories

The important parts:

My very convoluted list creation loop (entry2 = number of players on team)

```
  for i in range(int(entry2.get())):
    a = "z"
    for u in range(i):
        a += "z"
    player_list.insert(i - 1, a)
```

The loop that actually creates the entry boxes (pr = appropriate row)
    for n in player_list:

```
    pr += 1
    a= Entry(edit_roster, width = 15)
    a.grid(row = pr, column =3)
```

The function that saves values to a csv file (fn = filename, s = name w/o ".csv")

```
def save_new_file(s):
    global player_list
    fn = str(s) + ".csv"
    with open(fn, mode='w') as roster_file:
        roster_writer = csv.writer(roster_file, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
       for i in player_list:
            b = i.get()
            roster_writer.writerow([b, "player 1 "])
```

Basically I need to be able to create and reference variables using a string as it's name, or some way to convert a string into proper variable name so I can extract values from entry boxes created using said strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **Error** is occurring because you are calling `get()` method on strings.
Instead of calling `get()` method on `player_list`, do the following:

1. create a `entry_list`

   ```
   global entry_list
   entry_list = []
   ```
2. insert entries to entry list

   ```
   entry_list.append(a)
   ```
3. call `get()` method on entries from `entry_list`

   ```
   global entry_list
   for i in entry_list:
       print(i.get())
   ```

This is updated version of your code. Here I just printed the values from entries:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import simpledialog
import csv
import random

sample = Tk()
sample.geometry("500x500")


# lists


# functions
def switch_newroster():
    new_roster.tkraise()


def switch_startpage():
    start_page.tkraise()


def switch_loadroster():
    load_roster.tkraise()


def get_file():
    if entry_getfile_act.get() == "":
        messagebox.showerror("ERROR!!", "Please enter a file name")
    else:
        print("good job")


def create():
    global player_list

    # ADD_1 Create new global entry_list #####
    global entry_list
    entry_list = []

    player_list = []
    number_list = []

    pos_list = []

    pr = 3
    nr = 3
    gr = 3
    posr = 3
    ar = 3
    gaar = 3
    if entry2.get() == "":
        messagebox.showerror("ERROR!!", "Enter number of players")
        return False
    elif entry1.get() == "":
        messagebox.showerror("ERROR!!", "Please enter a team name")
        return False
    elif int(entry2.get()) > 35 or int(entry2.get()) <= 0:
        messagebox.showerror("ERROR!!", "Roster can contain 1-35 players")
    else:
        o = "we coolin my dude"
    for i in range(int(entry2.get())):
        a = "z"
        for u in range(i):
            a += "z"
        player_list.insert(i - 1, a)
    for i in range(int(entry2.get())):
        a = i + 1
        number_list.insert(i - 1, a)
    for i in range(int(entry2.get())):
        a = i + 1
        pos_list.insert(i - 1, a)

    print(player_list)
    team_name = Label(edit_roster, text=entry1.get())
    team_name.grid(row=1, column=3)
    for n in player_list:
        pr += 1
        n = StringVar()
        a = Entry(edit_roster, width=15, textvariable=n)
        a.grid(row=pr, column=3)

        # ADD_2 Append entries to entry_list #####
        entry_list.append(a)

    for n in number_list:
        nr += 1
        n = Entry(edit_roster, width=2)
        n.grid(row=nr, column=1)
    for n in pos_list:
        posr += 1
        pos = StringVar(sample)
        pos.set(n + 1)
        n = OptionMenu(edit_roster, pos, "G", "LW", "RW", "D")
        n.grid(row=posr, column=5)
    edit_roster.tkraise()


def editstats():
    goal_list = []
    assist_list = []
    gaa_list = []
    player_list = []
    number_list = []
    pos_list = []

    pr = 3
    nr = 3
    gr = 3
    posr = 3
    ar = 3
    gaar = 3

    lbl5 = Label(edit_stats, text="G")
    lbl5.grid(row=3, column=6)

    lbl6 = Label(edit_stats, text="A")
    lbl6.grid(row=3, column=5)

    lbl7 = Label(edit_stats, text="GAA")
    lbl7.grid(row=3, column=5)
    for i in range(int(entry2.get())):
        a = i + 1
        goal_list.insert(i - 1, a)
    for i in range(int(entry2.get())):
        a = i + 1
        gaa_list.insert(i - 1, a)
    for i in range(int(entry2.get())):
        a = "z"
        for u in range(i + 1):
            a += "z"
            assist_list.insert(i - 1, a)
    for n in goal_list:
        gr += 1
        n = Entry(edit_roster, width=2)
        n.grid(row=gr, column=4)
    for n in assist_list:
        ar += 1
        n = Entry(edit_roster, width=2)
        n.grid(row=ar, column=2)
    for n in gaa_list:
        gaar += 1
        n = Entry(edit_roster, width=2)
        n.grid(row=gaar, column=1)
    edit_roster.tkraise()


def save_new_file(s):
    global player_list

    # ADD_3 Get values from entries of entry_list #####
    global entry_list
    for i in entry_list:
        print(i.get())

    # fn = str(s) + ".csv"
    # with open(fn, mode='w') as roster_file:
    #     roster_writer = csv.writer(roster_file, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    #     roster_writer.writerow(['John Smith', 'Accounting', 'November'])
    #     roster_writer.writerow(['Erica Meyers', 'IT', 'March'])
    #     for i in player_list:
    #         b = i.get()
    #         roster_writer.writerow([b, "player 1 "])


def get_filename():
    global player_list
    print()
    filename = simpledialog.askstring("input string", "What do you want to call your file?")
    print(filename)
    save_new_file(filename)


# frames
# start page
start_page = Frame(sample, bg="pink", height="50", width="60")
start_page.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
# new roster
new_roster = Frame(sample, bg="yellow")
new_roster.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
# editable roster
edit_roster = Frame(sample, bg="Blue")
edit_roster.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
# load roster
load_roster = Frame(sample)
load_roster.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
# edit stats
edit_stats = Frame(sample)
edit_stats.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
start_page.tkraise()

# buttons
# start page
new_roster_b = Button(start_page, command=switch_newroster, text="NEW ROSTER", height="2", width="10")
new_roster_b.grid(row=1, column=2)

load_roster_b = Button(start_page, command=switch_loadroster, text="LOAD ROSTER", height="2", width="10")
load_roster_b.grid(row=2, column=2)

# load roster
entry_getfile_b = Button(load_roster, text="Find", command=get_file)
entry_getfile_b.grid(row=2, column=3)

back_b = Button(load_roster, command=switch_startpage, text="Back")
back_b.grid(row=3, column=1)

# new roster
back_b = Button(new_roster, command=switch_startpage, text="Back")
back_b.grid(row=3, column=1)

create_b = Button(new_roster, command=create, text="Create Team")
create_b.grid(row=2, column=5)

# edit roster
save_b = Button(edit_roster, command=get_filename, text="Save")
save_b.grid(row=3, column=6)

# other widgets

# start page

# load roster
entry_lbl_getfile = Label(load_roster, text="Enter File NAME!!!")
entry_lbl_getfile.grid(row=2, column=1)

entry_getfile_act = Entry(load_roster)
entry_getfile_act.grid(row=2, column=2)

# new roster
lbl1 = Label(new_roster, text="Team Name:")
lbl1.grid(row=2, column=1)

lbl8 = Label(new_roster, text="Number of Players:")
lbl8.grid(row=2, column=3)

entry1 = Entry(new_roster)
entry1.grid(row=2, column=2)

entry2 = Entry(new_roster)
entry2.grid(row=2, column=4)

# edit roster
lbl2 = Label(edit_roster, text="#")
lbl2.grid(row=3, column=1)

lbl3 = Label(edit_roster, text="Name")
lbl3.grid(row=3, column=3)

lbl4 = Label(edit_roster, text="Pos.")
lbl4.grid(row=3, column=5)

sample.mainloop()
```